# Huge selection radius from Icon Buttons MUI React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete, icons, iconbutton

just having some trouble getting rid of these huge selections on icon buttons which can be seen here:
[Large selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWenL.png)

I have found a fix is adding: component="span"

1. Why does this work/is this a bug? I should also mention I have tested this with the icon button not inside any other divs or any custom CSS and it still behaves the same.
2. How would I apply this component="span" fix to the autocomplete component which I believe uses icon buttons inside it, please see here: [Autocomplete icon button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8aqV.png). On the right the drop down arrow and cross buttons share this large selection and I assume are also Icon Buttons.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    import {createTheme} from "@material-ui/core";
    
     const themeSearch = createTheme({
        overrides: {
            MuiIconButton: {
                root: {
                    "&:hover": {
                        backgroundColor: 'transparent !important',
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    });

<ThemeProvider theme={themeSearch}>
  <div> your JSX </div>
</ThemeProvider>
```

Comment: "@material-ui/core": "4.12.1"

Comment: Hi Narek, that didn't seem to change anything on my end any ideas?

Comment: please write your code in https://codesandbox.io/ i will try to solve it